# Can enums be subclassed to add new elements?

Tags: java, enums

I want to take an existing enum and add more elements to it as follows:

```
enum A {a,b,c}

enum B extends A {d}

/*B is {a,b,c,d}*/
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: A reason to do this is for testing the situation where there is an invalid enum value without introducing an invalid enum value in the core source.

Comment: Yes an example of "linguistic" purity.  I think what is desired is for the "bookeeping" labor saving idea of an auto incrementing set of integers like one has in C++ so you can start a new set as an extension of the old set starting at the 1+ the last value of the prior set, and if the entries are named inherit the names from the "common subset".  Though the java enum has some nice things about it, it lacks the simple automated auto-incrementing integer declaring help that C++ enum provides.

Comment: Actually, when you extend your enum with new values, you're creating not subclass, but superclass. You can use base enum values everywhere instead of "extended" enum, but not vice versa, so according to Liskov Substitution Principle, extended enum is superclass of base enum.

Comment: @Ilya ... yes that is true.  I point out that the question has definite real-world use-cases.  For argument sake, consider a _base_ Enum of: `PrimaryColours`; it is reasonable to want to _**super**-class_ this to Enum `PrimaryAndPastelColours` by adding new colour names.  Liskov is still the elephant in the room.  So why not begin with a base Enum of: `AllMyColours` -- And then one _might_ **sub**-class all colours to: `PrimaryAndPastelColours` and subsequently **sub**-class this to: `PrimaryColours` (keeping the hierarchy in mind). Java won't permit that either though.

Answer (score 495, accepted):

No, you can't do this in Java. Aside from anything else, `d` would then presumably be an instance of `A` (given the normal idea of "extends"), but users who only knew about `A` wouldn't know about it - which defeats the point of an enum being a well-known set of values.

If you could tell us more about how you want to *use* this, we could potentially suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: The short explanation is that there is an existing enum that I would like to add more elements to, without modifying the original.

I was using 'extends' as an illustration of the idea, I didn't intend to restrict myself to the keyword.

Comment: You can't do this for exactly the reason I said before: an enum is meant to be a well-known set of values. If you could add elements to it, any existing code using it could suddenly get a nasty shock.

Comment: All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, an enum cannot extend anything else.

Comment: The reason I want to extend is because I'd like to have a base class called e.g. IntEnum, that looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681976/enum-with-int-value-in-java/1682018#1682018.  Then all my enums could extend it...in this case just benefitting from inheritance and thus I wouldn't have to duplicate this "int-based enum" code frequently.  I am new to Java and coming from C#, and I'm hoping I'm missing something.  My current opinion is that Java enums are a pain in comparison to C#.

Comment: @Tyler: C# enums are just names associated with numbers, with no automatic validation or *anything*. IMO enums are the one bit of Java which is actually better than C#.

Comment: Givanese gives the true reason, it's a language limitation. The contrived explanation about a well-known set of values is nonsense, this is a valid use case.

Comment: @npiv: It's a valid thing to want to be able to do, but it does conflict with other parts of how enums work. Basically there are conflicting requirements here.

Comment: Jon, I'm not sure I understand why this couldn't be supported.  What's wrong with the scenario where there are two classes generated, A extends Enum and B extends A (with d being an instance of B)?  In this case, instances of A could be passed to code that uses B when necessary, but values of type B would have to be cast explicitly if passed to code that was written for A (which would throw a ClassCastException in the case where the value was 'd'), which seems to satisfy all the necessary constraints...

Comment: @Jules: If B extends A, then surely any B value should be compatible with A by normal rules of Java. Changing that would be *very* confusing, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe a different keyword/concept ("includes"?) would help, because really you're creating a new enum instead of a "subEnum".  For example:  `enum StringMethodName includes enum ObjectMethodName`.  I would then find it logical that `StringMethodName.clone` throws a compile error when `ObjectMethodName` is expected, and that `ObjectMethodName.clone` compiles fine when `StringMethodName` is expected.

Comment: Not agreing with @JonSkeet here. In my use case, I would like to separate all the nasty logic in my big enum, and have the logic hidden away, and define a clean enum that extends the other one that is hidden. Enums with lots of logic beats the idea of having clean variables declared so you do not have to declare hundreds of static strings variables so a class with 5 enums dont get unreadable and too big in lines. I do not want the other developers to be concerned with copying and pasting that peace of code for the next project either and instead extend the base_enum ... it makes sense to me...

Comment: @Hamidam: Why would the "clean" enum need to *extend* the other one? Why couldn't it just *use* it internally? Sorry, it's not really clear from your comment why you think inheritance is desirable here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Here's a use case: Create an AuditFields class most db entities extend (DRY). One audit field is 'update_action varchar(60)'. Using a string enum in the field forces standard'n making it useful. But there will be many enums for the field, too many to make it maintainable or sane for the coders using it. Solution: create enum super and extend it (can't). Use the super to define the entity field. Extend the super broken out by application functional area reducing the values per enum and making it useful. Only sol'n now is old school interface static fields which don't force their use.

Comment: @givanse... not agreeing with you on the point of implicit extension of java.lang.Enum being the cause of non-inheritance as every class in java also implicitly inherits Object class yet it can inherit some other class as it would then come into the hierarchy as `Object->A->B` instead of `Object->A->B extends Object`

Comment: Completely disagree with @givanse and @npiv here: It's got nothing to do with multiple inheritence as @mickeymoon correctly explains. The real reason is because `extends` is an "is-a" relationship and a subclass can therefore be used anywhere its superclass is required, but (using the OP's example) `d` would not be a valid value for type `A`, and so cannot be passed in where A is required. (As an aside, the only way extending an enum could conceptually fit in with Java's extends model is if the sub-enums allowed only a subset of their super-enum; think set theory in mathematics.)

Comment: Old answer but... @daiscog Oracle agrees with the multiple inheritance explanation: "Note: All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Because a class can only extend one parent (see Declaring Classes), the Java language does not support multiple inheritance of state (see Multiple Inheritance of State, Implementation, and Type), and therefore an enum cannot extend anything else."  From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html.  Mickeymoon, all classes implicitly extend Object - unless they explicitly extend something else.

Comment: @nasch I think that Oracle are referring to extending a non-enum parent class with an enum base class.  In the question, the poster wants to extend another enum, which itself already extends `java.lang.Enum`, therefore it isn't multiple inheritance.

Comment: @daiscog You cannot extend an enum with another enum as discussed, and you cannot extend one with a class either.  According to my IDE it's because the enum is implicitly final, but I believe if you try it you will encounter an error.

Comment: @nasch Yes exactly:  The reason you can't extend an enum with another enum is because enums are implicitly final; which is nothing to do with multiple inheritance.

Comment: @daiscog Why can't it be both?  Being implicitly final wouldn't prevent an enum from extending a class, but implicitly extending Enum does.

Comment: @nasch The question isn't about extending a class, it's about extending another enum.  Yes, if enums were not implicitly final then the lack of multiple inheritance support would prevent them extending a non-enum class.  But the question was why can't one enum extend another enum.  The answer is:  Because enums are final.

Comment: @daiscog If the question is "why can't an enum extend another enum" then "because it's already extending Enum implicitly" is also a valid and sufficient answer.  Neither is wrong.  Either fact by itself would be enough to prevent it, so you can't do it for both reasons.

Comment: Because `B.a`, `B.b` and `B.c` would have different function set to `B.d` if it was possible.. Since `B.a` is not of class `B` but of class `A`. B **could** have additional methods added.

Answer (score 335):

Enums represent a complete enumeration of possible values. So the (unhelpful) answer is no.

As an example of a real problem take weekdays, weekend days and, the union, days of week. We could define all days within days-of-week but then we would not be able to represent properties special to either weekdays and weekend-days.

What we could do, is have three enum types with a mapping between weekdays/weekend-days and days-of-week.

```
public enum Weekday {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI;
    public DayOfWeek toDayOfWeek() { ... }
}
public enum WeekendDay {
    SAT, SUN;
    public DayOfWeek toDayOfWeek() { ... }
}
public enum DayOfWeek {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN;
}
```

Alternatively, we could have an open-ended interface for day-of-week:

```
interface Day {
    ...
}
public enum Weekday implements Day {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI;
}
public enum WeekendDay implements Day {
    SAT, SUN;
}
```

Or we could combine the two approaches:

```
interface Day {
    ...
}
public enum Weekday implements Day {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI;
    public DayOfWeek toDayOfWeek() { ... }
}
public enum WeekendDay implements Day {
    SAT, SUN;
    public DayOfWeek toDayOfWeek() { ... }
}
public enum DayOfWeek {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN;
    public Day toDay() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a problem with this? A switch statement won't work on an interface, but it works on a regular enum. Not working w/switch kind of kills one of the nicer things about enums.

Comment: @Crusader With the second approach, yeah you'd have to use an `if`-`else` chain or something. With the first approach there is no interface. With the third, you'd need to call `toDayOfWeek` if you have a `Day` reference.

Comment: I'm thinking there might be another problem with this.  There is no equality between the Weekday.MON and DayOfWeek.MON.  Isn't that the other big benefit of enums?  I don't have a better solution, just realizing this as I'm trying to find the best answer.  The lack of being able to use == forces the hand a bit.

Comment: @Snekse There is certainly an issue that the compiler wont (currently don't watn - I guess it could be added) if you accidentally compare a `Weekday` to `DayOfWeek.MON`, or similar using `Object.equals`, `Map.get`, `List.indexOf`, etc. (See http://smallwig.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html )

Comment: @Crusader yes, that's precisely the trade-off.  If you want something expandable you can't have fixed switch statements, if you want a set of fixed known values you tautologically can't have something expandable.

Comment: Going from enum to interface, you also lose the static call to values().  This makes refactoring hard, especially if you decide to extend your enum and add the interface as an abstraction barrier to an established enum.

Comment: you have out-skeeted skeet!!

Comment: This approach of deriving an enum from an interface is used by the Java 1.7 API, e.g. java.nio.file.Files.write() takes an array of OpenOption as the last argument. OpenOption is an interface, but when we call this function we usually pass a StandardOpenOption enum constant, which is derived from OpenOption. This has the advantage of being extensible, but it also has drawbacks. The implementation suffers from the fact OpenOption is an interface. It creates a HashSet<OpenOption> from the passed array, when it could have created a more space- and time-efficient EnumSet. And it can't use switch.

Answer (score 79):

The recommended solution to this is the [extensible enum pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/java-extensible-enum-with-interface).

This involves creating an interface and using that where you currently use the enum. Then make the enum implement the interface. You can add more constants by adding an additional enum/class that also extends the interface. Here is the general idea:

```
public interface TrafficLights {
  public abstract String getColour();
}
public enum StandardTrafficLights implements TrafficLights {
  RED, YELLOW, GREEN;
  public String getColour() {
    return name();
  }
}
public enum WeirdTrafficLights implements TrafficLights {
  DOUBLE_RED;
  public String getColour() {
    return name();
  }
}
```

Note that if you want something like `TrafficLights.valueof(String)` you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: It's worth calling out their use of a factory method in the interface.  Great way to share common functionality between related Enums given that extending is not a viable solution.

Comment: Can you provide more details (code :)) about this pattern?

Comment: That pattern does not permit to extend an enum's values. Which is the point in the question asked.

Comment: Sadly this answer is not very helpful now anymore because the link it relied on is now gone.

Answer (score 61):

Under the covers your ENUM is just a regular class generated by the compiler. That generated class extends `java.lang.Enum`. The technical reason you can't extend the generated class is that the generated class is `final`. The conceptual reasons for it being final are discussed in this topic. But I'll add the mechanics to the discussion.

Here is a test enum:

```
public enum TEST {  
    ONE, TWO, THREE;
}
```

The resulting code from javap:

```
public final class TEST extends java.lang.Enum<TEST> {
  public static final TEST ONE;
  public static final TEST TWO;
  public static final TEST THREE;
  static {};
  public static TEST[] values();
  public static TEST valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Conceivably you could type this class on your own and drop the "final". But the compiler prevents you from extending "java.lang.Enum" directly. You could decide NOT to extend java.lang.Enum, but then your class and its derived classes would not be an instanceof java.lang.Enum ... which might not really matter to you any way!

Comment: What is the empty static block doing? 'static {};'

Comment: It has no code in it. The "javap" program shows the empty block.

Comment: Strange to have it there if it's not doing anything isn't it?

Comment: You are right! My mistake. It is NOT an empty block of code. If you run "javap -c" you will see the actual code inside the static block. The static block creates all the ENUM instances (ONE, TWO, and THREE here). Sorry about that.

Comment: Just for kicks, I tried typing the class that you got from `javap` directly to see if I could drop the final. No dice. The complier will not let me extend `Enum` explicitly. (It doesn't matter whether or not I call my class `final` - The error occurs from the attempt to extend `Enum`.)

Comment: Thanks for stating the straight fact: because java.lang.Enum is declared final.

Comment: @Brick: you can do that when you use an *older* compiler, which doesn’t know the rule that extending `Enum` manually is not allowed.

Answer (score 30):

```
enum A {a,b,c}
enum B extends A {d}
/*B is {a,b,c,d}*/
```

can be written as:

```
public enum All {
    a       (ClassGroup.A,ClassGroup.B),
    b       (ClassGroup.A,ClassGroup.B),
    c       (ClassGroup.A,ClassGroup.B),
    d       (ClassGroup.B) 
...
```

- *ClassGroup.B.getMembers()* contains {a,b,c,d}

**How it can be useful:** Let say we want something like:
We have events and we are using enums. Those enums can be grouped by similar processing. If we have operation with many elements, then some events starts operation, some are just step and other end the operation. To gather such operation and avoid long switch case we can group them as in example and use:

```
if(myEvent.is(State_StatusGroup.START)) makeNewOperationObject()..
if(myEnum.is(State_StatusGroup.STEP)) makeSomeSeriousChanges()..
if(myEnum.is(State_StatusGroup.FINISH)) closeTransactionOrSomething()..
```

Example:

```
public enum AtmOperationStatus {
STARTED_BY_SERVER       (State_StatusGroup.START),
SUCCESS             (State_StatusGroup.FINISH),
FAIL_TOKEN_TIMEOUT      (State_StatusGroup.FAIL, 
                    State_StatusGroup.FINISH),
FAIL_NOT_COMPLETE       (State_StatusGroup.FAIL,
                    State_StatusGroup.STEP),
FAIL_UNKNOWN            (State_StatusGroup.FAIL,
                    State_StatusGroup.FINISH),
(...)

private AtmOperationStatus(StatusGroupInterface ... pList){
    for (StatusGroupInterface group : pList){
        group.addMember(this);
    }
}
public boolean is(StatusGroupInterface with){
    for (AtmOperationStatus eT : with.getMembers()){
        if( eT .equals(this))   return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// Each group must implement this interface
private interface StatusGroupInterface{
    EnumSet<AtmOperationStatus> getMembers();
    void addMember(AtmOperationStatus pE);
}
// DEFINING GROUPS
public enum State_StatusGroup implements StatusGroupInterface{
    START, STEP, FAIL, FINISH;

    private List<AtmOperationStatus> members = new LinkedList<AtmOperationStatus>();

    @Override
    public EnumSet<AtmOperationStatus> getMembers() {
        return EnumSet.copyOf(members);
    }

    @Override
    public void addMember(AtmOperationStatus pE) {
        members.add(pE);
    }
    static { // forcing initiation of dependent enum
        try {
            Class.forName(AtmOperationStatus.class.getName()); 
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { 
            throw new RuntimeException("Class AtmEventType not found", ex); 
        }
    }
}
}
//Some use of upper code:
if (p.getStatus().is(AtmOperationStatus.State_StatusGroup.FINISH)) {
    //do something
}else if (p.getStatus().is(AtmOperationStatus.State_StatusGroup.START)) {
    //do something      
}
```

Add some more advanced:

```
public enum AtmEventType {

USER_DEPOSIT        (Status_EventsGroup.WITH_STATUS,
              Authorization_EventsGroup.USER_AUTHORIZED,
              ChangedMoneyAccountState_EventsGroup.CHANGED,
              OperationType_EventsGroup.DEPOSIT,
              ApplyTo_EventsGroup.CHANNEL),
SERVICE_DEPOSIT     (Status_EventsGroup.WITH_STATUS,
              Authorization_EventsGroup.TERMINAL_AUTHORIZATION,
              ChangedMoneyAccountState_EventsGroup.CHANGED,
              OperationType_EventsGroup.DEPOSIT,
              ApplyTo_EventsGroup.CHANNEL),
DEVICE_MALFUNCTION  (Status_EventsGroup.WITHOUT_STATUS,
              Authorization_EventsGroup.TERMINAL_AUTHORIZATION,
              ChangedMoneyAccountState_EventsGroup.DID_NOT_CHANGED,
              ApplyTo_EventsGroup.DEVICE),
CONFIGURATION_4_C_CHANGED(Status_EventsGroup.WITHOUT_STATUS,
              ApplyTo_EventsGroup.TERMINAL,
              ChangedMoneyAccountState_EventsGroup.DID_NOT_CHANGED),
(...)
```

At above if we have some fail (myEvent.is(State_StatusGroup.FAIL)) then iterating by previous events we can easily check if we must revert money transfer by:

```
if(myEvent2.is(ChangedMoneyAccountState_EventsGroup.CHANGED)) rollBack()..
```

It can be useful for:

> 1. including explicite meta-data about processing logic, less to remember
> 2. implementing some of multi-inheritance
> 3. we don't want to use class structures, ex. for sending short status messages

Comment: This is a brilliant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 16):

In case you missed it, there's a chapter in the excellent Joshua Bloch's book "[Effective Java, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)".

- Chapter 6 - Enums and Annotations
- Item 34 : **Emulate extensible enums with interfaces**

Just the conclusion :

> A minor disadvantage of the use of interfaces to emulate extensible enums is
> those implementations cannot be inherited from one enum type to another. In the
> case of our Operation example, the logic to store and retrieve the symbol associated
> with an operation is duplicated in BasicOperation and ExtendedOperation.
> In this case, it doesn’t matter because very little code is duplicated. If there were a
> a larger amount of shared functionality, you could encapsulate it in a helper class or
> a static helper method to eliminate the code duplication.

> In summary, while you cannot write an extensible enum type, you can
> emulate it by writing an interface to go with a basic enum type that implements
> the interface. This allows clients to write their own enums that implement
> the interface. These enums can then be used wherever the basic enum type can be
> used, assuming APIs are written in terms of the interface.

Comment: For anyone with the updated Effective Java, Third edition: the same pattern is discussed in Chapter 6, item 38 (page 176). Chapter and item titles haven't changed.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a way how I found how to extend a enum into other enum, is a very straighfoward approach:

Suposse you have a enum with common constants:

```
public interface ICommonInterface {

    String getName();

}


public enum CommonEnum implements ICommonInterface {
    P_EDITABLE("editable"),
    P_ACTIVE("active"),
    P_ID("id");

    private final String name;

    EnumCriteriaComun(String name) {
        name= name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

then you can try to do a manual extends in this way:

```
public enum SubEnum implements ICommonInterface {
    P_EDITABLE(CommonEnum.P_EDITABLE ),
    P_ACTIVE(CommonEnum.P_ACTIVE),
    P_ID(CommonEnum.P_ID),
    P_NEW_CONSTANT("new_constant");

    private final String name;

    EnumCriteriaComun(CommonEnum commonEnum) {
        name= commonEnum.name;
    }

    EnumCriteriaComun(String name) {
        name= name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

of course every time you need to extend a constant you have to modify your SubEnum files.

Comment: interesting, we could use also the very enum toString(), and at the end compare strings; and to use switch, we would just have to cast the object to a known enum; the sole problem would be 2 developers extending and creating an identical enum id, and later trying to merge both codes :), now I think I understand why enum should remain non extendable.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I enhance the enum inheritance pattern with runtime check in static initializer.
The `BaseKind#checkEnumExtender` checks that "extending" enum declares all the values of the base enum in exactly the same way so `#name()` and `#ordinal()` remain fully compatible.

There is still copy-paste involved for declaring values but the program fails fast if somebody added or modified a value in the base class without updating extending ones.

*Common behavior for different enums extending each other:*

```
public interface Kind {
  /**
   * Let's say we want some additional member.
   */
  String description() ;

  /**
   * Standard {@code Enum} method.
   */
  String name() ;

  /**
   * Standard {@code Enum} method.
   */
  int ordinal() ;
}
```

*Base enum, with verifying method:*

```
public enum BaseKind implements Kind {

  FIRST( "First" ),
  SECOND( "Second" ),

  ;

  private final String description ;

  public String description() {
    return description ;
  }

  private BaseKind( final String description ) {
    this.description = description ;
  }

  public static void checkEnumExtender(
      final Kind[] baseValues,
      final Kind[] extendingValues
  ) {
    if( extendingValues.length < baseValues.length ) {
      throw new IncorrectExtensionError( "Only " + extendingValues.length + " values against "
          + baseValues.length + " base values" ) ;
    }
    for( int i = 0 ; i < baseValues.length ; i ++ ) {
      final Kind baseValue = baseValues[ i ] ;
      final Kind extendingValue = extendingValues[ i ] ;
      if( baseValue.ordinal() != extendingValue.ordinal() ) {
        throw new IncorrectExtensionError( "Base ordinal " + baseValue.ordinal()
            + " doesn't match with " + extendingValue.ordinal() ) ;
      }
      if( ! baseValue.name().equals( extendingValue.name() ) ) {
        throw new IncorrectExtensionError( "Base name[ " + i + "] " + baseValue.name()
            + " doesn't match with " + extendingValue.name() ) ;
      }
      if( ! baseValue.description().equals( extendingValue.description() ) ) {
        throw new IncorrectExtensionError( "Description[ " + i + "] " + baseValue.description()
            + " doesn't match with " + extendingValue.description() ) ;
      }
    }
  }


  public static class IncorrectExtensionError extends Error {
    public IncorrectExtensionError( final String s ) {
      super( s ) ;
    }
  }

}
```

*Extension sample:*

```
public enum ExtendingKind implements Kind {
  FIRST( BaseKind.FIRST ),
  SECOND( BaseKind.SECOND ),
  THIRD( "Third" ),
  ;

  private final String description ;

  public String description() {
    return description ;
  }

  ExtendingKind( final BaseKind baseKind ) {
    this.description = baseKind.description() ;
  }

  ExtendingKind( final String description ) {
    this.description = description ;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Based on @Tom Hawtin - tackline** answer we add switch support,

```
interface Day<T> {
    ...
  T valueOf();
}

public enum Weekday implements Day<Weekday> {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI;
   Weekday valueOf(){
     return valueOf(name());
   }
}

public enum WeekendDay implements Day<WeekendDay> {
    SAT, SUN;
   WeekendDay valueOf(){
     return valueOf(name());
   }
}

Day<Weekday> wds = Weekday.MON;
Day<WeekendDay> wends = WeekendDay.SUN;

switch(wds.valueOf()){
    case MON:
    case TUE:
    case WED:
    case THU:
    case FRI:
}

switch(wends.valueOf()){
    case SAT:
    case SUN:
}
```

Comment: What's the use of the `valueOf()` method?

Comment: @AxelAdvento The idea here is we depend on the interface `Day` that has method `valueOf()` then `switch(Day.valueOf())`, it's implemented by `WeekDay, WeekEndDay` enums.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to avoid enums, because they are not extensible. To stay with the example of the OP, if A is in a library and B in your own code, you can't extend A if it is an enum. This is how I sometimes replace enums:

```
// access like enum: A.a
public class A {
    public static final A a = new A();
    public static final A b = new A();
    public static final A c = new A();
/*
 * In case you need to identify your constant
 * in different JVMs, you need an id. This is the case if
 * your object is transfered between
 * different JVM instances (eg. save/load, or network).
 * Also, switch statements don't work with
 * Objects, but work with int.
 */
    public static int maxId=0;
    public int id = maxId++;
    public int getId() { return id; }
}

public class B extends A {
/*
 * good: you can do like
 * A x = getYourEnumFromSomeWhere();
 * if(x instanceof B) ...;
 * to identify which enum x
 * is of.
 */
    public static final A d = new A();
}

public class C extends A {
/* Good: e.getId() != d.getId()
 * Bad: in different JVMs, C and B
 * might be initialized in different order,
 * resulting in different IDs.
 * Workaround: use a fixed int, or hash code.
 */
    public static final A e = new A();
    public int getId() { return -32489132; };
}
```

There are some pits to avoid, see the comments in the code. Depending on your needs, this is a solid, extensible alternative to enums.

Comment: it may be fine if you just need some ordinal for instances. But enums also hava a name property that is pretty useful.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take the other way around approach.

Instead of extending the existing enumeration, create a larger one and create a subset of it.
For exemple if you had an enumeration called PET and you wanted to extend it to ANIMAL you should do this instead:

```
public enum ANIMAL {
    WOLF,CAT, DOG
} 
EnumSet<ANIMAL> pets = EnumSet.of(ANIMAL.CAT, ANIMAL.DOG);
```

Be careful, pets is not an immutable collections, you might want to use Guava or Java9 for more safety.

Answer (score 3):

As an aid to understanding why extending an Enum is not reasonable at the language implementation level to consider what would happen if you passed an instance of the extended Enum to a routine that only understands the base Enum. A switch that the compiler promised had all cases covered would in fact not cover those extended Enum values.

This further emphasizes that Java Enum values are not integers such as C's are, for instances: to use a Java Enum as an array index you must explicitly ask for its ordinal() member, to give a java Enum an arbitrary integer value you must add an explicit field for that and reference that named member.

This is not a comment on the OP's desire, just on why Java ain't never going to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Having had this same problem myself I'd like to post my perspective. I think that there are a couple motivating factors for doing something like this:

- You want to have some related enum codes, but in different classes. In my case I had a base class with several codes defined in an associated enum. At some later date (today!) I wanted to provide some new functionality to the base class, which also meant new codes for the enum.
- The derived class would support both the base classes' enum as well as its own. No duplicate enum values! So: how to have an enum for the subclass that includes the enum's of its parent along with its new values.

Using an interface doesn't really cut it: you can accidentally get duplicate enum values. Not desirable.

I ended up just combining the enums: this ensures that there cannot be any duplicate values, at the expense of being less tightly tied to its associated class. But, I figured the duplicate issue was my main concern...

Answer (score 2):

In the hopes this elegant solution of a colleague of mine is even seen in this long post I'd like to share this approach for subclassing which follows the interface approach and beyond.

Please be aware that we use custom exceptions here and this code won't compile unless you replace it with your exceptions.

The documentation is extensive and I hope it's understandable for most of you.

The interface that every subclassed enum needs to implement.

```
public interface Parameter {
  /**
   * Retrieve the parameters name.
   *
   * @return the name of the parameter
   */
  String getName();

  /**
   * Retrieve the parameters type.
   *
   * @return the {@link Class} according to the type of the parameter
   */
  Class<?> getType();

  /**
   * Matches the given string with this parameters value pattern (if applicable). This helps to find
   * out if the given string is a syntactically valid candidate for this parameters value.
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string to check for
   * @return <code>true</code> in case this parameter has no pattern defined or the given string
   *         matches the defined one, <code>false</code> in case <code>valueStr</code> is
   *         <code>null</code> or an existing pattern is not matched
   */
  boolean match(final String valueStr);

  /**
   * This method works as {@link #match(String)} but throws an exception if not matched.
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string to check for
   * @throws ArgumentException with code
   *           <dl>
   *           <dt>PARAM_MISSED</dt>
   *           <dd>if <code>valueStr</code> is <code>null</code></dd>
   *           <dt>PARAM_BAD</dt>
   *           <dd>if pattern is not matched</dd>
   *           </dl>
   */
  void matchEx(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException;

  /**
   * Parses a value for this parameter from the given string. This method honors the parameters data
   * type and potentially other criteria defining a valid value (e.g. a pattern).
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string to parse the parameter value from
   * @return the parameter value according to the parameters type (see {@link #getType()}) or
   *         <code>null</code> in case <code>valueStr</code> was <code>null</code>.
   * @throws ArgumentException in case <code>valueStr</code> is not parsable as a value for this
   *           parameter.
   */
  Object parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException;

  /**
   * Converts the given value to its external form as it is accepted by {@link #parse(String)}. For
   * most (ordinary) parameters this is simply a call to {@link String#valueOf(Object)}. In case the
   * parameter types {@link Object#toString()} method does not return the external form (e.g. for
   * enumerations), this method has to be implemented accordingly.
   *
   * @param value <i>mandatory</i> - the parameters value
   * @return the external form of the parameters value, never <code>null</code>
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the given <code>value</code> does not match
   *           {@link #getType()}
   */
  String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException;
}
```

The implementing ENUM base class.

```
public enum Parameters implements Parameter {
  /**
   * ANY ENUM VALUE
   */
  VALUE(new ParameterImpl<String>("VALUE", String.class, "[A-Za-z]{3,10}"));

  /**
   * The parameter wrapped by this enum constant.
   */
  private Parameter param;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param param <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #param}
   */
  private Parameters(final Parameter param) {
    this.param = param;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.param.getName();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Class<?> getType() {
    return this.param.getType();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean match(final String valueStr) {
    return this.param.match(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void matchEx(final String valueStr) {
    this.param.matchEx(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Object parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException {
    return this.param.parse(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    return this.param.toString(value);
  }
}
```

The subclassed ENUM which "inherits" from base class.

```
public enum ExtendedParameters implements Parameter {
  /**
   * ANY ENUM VALUE
   */
  VALUE(my.package.name.VALUE);

  /**
   * EXTENDED ENUM VALUE
   */
  EXTENDED_VALUE(new ParameterImpl<String>("EXTENDED_VALUE", String.class, "[0-9A-Za-z_.-]{1,20}"));

  /**
   * The parameter wrapped by this enum constant.
   */
  private Parameter param;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param param <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #param}
   */
  private Parameters(final Parameter param) {
    this.param = param;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.param.getName();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Class<?> getType() {
    return this.param.getType();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean match(final String valueStr) {
    return this.param.match(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void matchEx(final String valueStr) {
    this.param.matchEx(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Object parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException {
    return this.param.parse(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    return this.param.toString(value);
  }
}
```

Finally the generic ParameterImpl to add some utilities.

```
public class ParameterImpl<T> implements Parameter {
  /**
   * The default pattern for numeric (integer, long) parameters.
   */
  private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");

  /**
   * The default pattern for parameters of type boolean.
   */
  private static final Pattern BOOLEAN_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("0|1|true|false");

  /**
   * The name of the parameter, never <code>null</code>.
   */
  private final String name;

  /**
   * The data type of the parameter.
   */
  private final Class<T> type;

  /**
   * The validation pattern for the parameters values. This may be <code>null</code>.
   */
  private final Pattern validator;

  /**
   * Shortcut constructor without <code>validatorPattern</code>.
   *
   * @param name <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #name}
   * @param type <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #type}
   */
  public ParameterImpl(final String name, final Class<T> type) {
    this(name, type, null);
  }

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param name <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #name}
   * @param type <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #type}
   * @param validatorPattern - <i>optional</i> - the pattern for {@link #validator}
   *          <dl>
   *          <dt style="margin-top:0.25cm;"><i>Note:</i>
   *          <dd>The default validation patterns {@link #NUMBER_PATTERN} or
   *          {@link #BOOLEAN_PATTERN} are applied accordingly.
   *          </dl>
   */
  public ParameterImpl(final String name, final Class<T> type, final String validatorPattern) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    if (null != validatorPattern) {
      this.validator = Pattern.compile(validatorPattern);

    } else if (Integer.class == this.type || Long.class == this.type) {
      this.validator = NUMBER_PATTERN;
    } else if (Boolean.class == this.type) {
      this.validator = BOOLEAN_PATTERN;
    } else {
      this.validator = null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean match(final String valueStr) {
    if (null == valueStr) {
      return false;
    }
    if (null != this.validator) {
      final Matcher matcher = this.validator.matcher(valueStr);
      return matcher.matches();
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void matchEx(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException {
    if (false == this.match(valueStr)) {
      if (null == valueStr) {
        throw ArgumentException.createEx(ErrorCode.PARAM_MISSED, "The value must not be null",
            this.name);
      }
      throw ArgumentException.createEx(ErrorCode.PARAM_BAD, "The value must match the pattern: "
          + this.validator.pattern(), this.name);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Parse the parameters value from the given string value according to {@link #type}. Additional
   * the value is checked by {@link #matchEx(String)}.
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string value to parse the value from
   * @return the parsed value, may be <code>null</code>
   * @throws ArgumentException in case the parameter:
   *           <ul>
   *           <li>does not {@link #matchEx(String)} the {@link #validator}</li>
   *           <li>cannot be parsed according to {@link #type}</li>
   *           </ul>
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the type {@link #type} cannot be handled. This is a
   *           programming error.
   */
  @Override
  public T parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException, InternalServiceException {
    if (null == valueStr) {
      return null;
    }
    this.matchEx(valueStr);

    if (String.class == this.type) {
      return this.type.cast(valueStr);
    }
    if (Boolean.class == this.type) {
      return this.type.cast(Boolean.valueOf(("1".equals(valueStr)) || Boolean.valueOf(valueStr)));
    }
    try {
      if (Integer.class == this.type) {
        return this.type.cast(Integer.valueOf(valueStr));
      }
      if (Long.class == this.type) {
        return this.type.cast(Long.valueOf(valueStr));
      }
    } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
      throw ArgumentException.createEx(ErrorCode.PARAM_BAD, "The value cannot be parsed as "
          + this.type.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + ".", this.name);
    }

    return this.parseOther(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * Field access for {@link #name}.
   *
   * @return the value of {@link #name}.
   */
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  /**
   * Field access for {@link #type}.
   *
   * @return the value of {@link #type}.
   */
  @Override
  public Class<T> getType() {
    return this.type;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public final String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    if (false == this.type.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
      throw new InternalServiceException(ErrorCode.PANIC,
          "Parameter.toString(): Bad type of value. Expected {0} but is {1}.", this.type.getName(),
          value.getClass().getName());
    }
    if (String.class == this.type || Integer.class == this.type || Long.class == this.type) {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    if (Boolean.class == this.type) {
      return Boolean.TRUE.equals(value) ? "1" : "0";
    }

    return this.toStringOther(value);
  }

  /**
   * Parse parameter values of other (non standard types). This method is called by
   * {@link #parse(String)} in case {@link #type} is none of the supported standard types (currently
   * String, Boolean, Integer and Long). It is intended for extensions.
   * <dl>
   * <dt style="margin-top:0.25cm;"><i>Note:</i>
   * <dd>This default implementation always throws an InternalServiceException.
   * </dl>
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>mandatory</i> - the string value to parse the value from
   * @return the parsed value, may be <code>null</code>
   * @throws ArgumentException in case the parameter cannot be parsed according to {@link #type}
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the type {@link #type} cannot be handled. This is a
   *           programming error.
   */
  protected T parseOther(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException, InternalServiceException {
    throw new InternalServiceException(ErrorCode.PANIC,
        "ParameterImpl.parseOther(): Unsupported parameter type: " + this.type.getName());
  }

  /**
   * Convert the values of other (non standard types) to their external form. This method is called
   * by {@link #toString(Object)} in case {@link #type} is none of the supported standard types
   * (currently String, Boolean, Integer and Long). It is intended for extensions.
   * <dl>
   * <dt style="margin-top:0.25cm;"><i>Note:</i>
   * <dd>This default implementation always throws an InternalServiceException.
   * </dl>
   *
   * @param value <i>mandatory</i> - the parameters value
   * @return the external form of the parameters value, never <code>null</code>
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the given <code>value</code> does not match
   *           {@link #getClass()}
   */
  protected String toStringOther(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    throw new InternalServiceException(ErrorCode.PANIC,
        "ParameterImpl.toStringOther(): Unsupported parameter type: " + this.type.getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My way to code that would be as follows:

```
// enum A { a, b, c }
static final Set<Short> enumA = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Short[]{'a','b','c'}));

// enum B extends A { d }
static final Set<Short> enumB = new LinkedHashSet<>(enumA);
static {
    enumB.add((short) 'd');
    // If you have to add more elements:
    // enumB.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Short[]{ 'e', 'f', 'g', '♯', '♭' }));
}
```

`LinkedHashSet` provides both that each entry only exists once, and that their order is preserved. If order doesn’t matter, you can use `HashSet` instead. The following code is **not possible** in Java:

```
for (A a : B.values()) { // enum B extends A { d }
    switch (a) {
        case a:
        case b:
        case c:
            System.out.println("Value is: " + a.toString());
        break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("This should never happen.");
    }
}
```

The code can be written as follows:

```
for (Short a : enumB) {
    switch (a) {
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
            System.out.println("Value is: " + new String(Character.toChars(a)));
        break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("This should never happen.");
    }
}
```

From Java 7 onwards you can even do the same with `String`:

```
// enum A { BACKWARDS, FOREWARDS, STANDING }
static final Set<String> enumA = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {
        "BACKWARDS", "FOREWARDS", "STANDING" }));

// enum B extends A { JUMP }
static final Set<String> enumB = new LinkedHashSet<>(enumA);
static {
    enumB.add("JUMP");
}
```

Using the enum replacement:

```
for (String a : enumB) {
    switch (a) {
        case "BACKWARDS":
        case "FOREWARDS":
        case "STANDING":
            System.out.println("Value is: " + a);
        break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("This should never happen.");
    }
}
```