# Enum with int value in Java

Tags: c#, java, enums

What's the Java equivalent of C#'s:

```
enum Foo
{
  Bar = 0,
  Baz = 1,
  Fii = 10,
}
```

Comment: I am actually embarrassed for Java that enums with different int values doesn't just work.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you want attributes for your `enum` you need to define it like this:

```
public enum Foo {
    BAR (0),
    BAZ (1),
    FII (10);

    private final int index;   

    Foo(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int index() { 
        return index; 
    }

}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Foo f : Foo.values()) {
       System.out.printf("%s has index %d%n", f, f.index());
    }
}
```

The thing to realise is that `enum` is just a shortcut for creating a class, so you can add whatever attributes and methods you want to the class.

If you don't want to define any methods on your `enum` you could change the scope of the member variables and make them `public`, but that's not what they do in the [example on the Sun website](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Comment: +1 for including the accessor :)

Note that to get to the numerical value, you'd have to use Foo.BAR.index()

Comment: Note also, that if you want to get to the enum from the int code, you shoudl also add a static method that do the reverse mapping (with a switch or a map).

Comment: @penpen - a switch is a bummer to maintain; do the map, or just do a linear search, it's not that bad (except when it is)

Comment: I would not call this index but val instead as for example the index (ordinal) of FII in this code is 2 (assuming zero based indexing) while its value is 10.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a contiguous range of values, and all you need is the integer value, you can just declare the enum minimally:

```
public enum NUMBERZ {
        ZERO, ONE, TWO
}
```

and then obtain the int value as follows:

```
int numberOne = NUMBERZ.ONE.ordinal();
```

However, if you need a discontiguous range (as in your example, where you jump from 1 to 10) then you will need to write your own enum constructor which sets your own member variable, and provide a get method for that variable, as described in the other answers here.

Answer (score 4):

It is:

```
enum Foo
{
  Bar(0),
  Baz(1),
  Fii(10);

  private int index;

  private Foo(int index) {
      this.index = index;
  }
}
```

Note that to get the value of the enum from the index, `Foo.valueOf(1)` (*), would not work. You need do code it yourself:

```
public Foo getFooFromIndex(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return Foo.Bar;
    case 1:
        return Foo.Baz;
    case 10:
        return Foo.Fii;

    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown index:" + index);
    }
}
```

---

(*): Enum.valueOf() return the enum from a String. As such, you can get the value Bar with `Foo.valueOf('Bar')`

Comment: Instead of that hand-coded method, lazily initialize a Map<Foo,Integer>.

(for example using Maps.uniqueIndex() from Google Collections.)

Comment: Too bad it's not possible to use Bar.index, Baz.index etc in the switch because they aren't constant expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
public enum Foo {
    Bar(0),
    Baz(1),
    Fii(10);

    private int number;

    public Foo(int number) {
       this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

For starters, Sun's [Java Enum Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) would be a great place to learn more.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access, not public.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Foo {
    Bar(0),
    Baz(1),
    Fii(10);

    private final int someint;
    Foo(int someint) {
        this.someint = someint;
    }
}
```

In Java enums are very similar to other classes but the the Java compiler knows to treat a little differently in various situations. So if you want data in them like you seem to you need to have an instance variable for the data and an appropriate constructor.