# Help with enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum that looks like this

```
public enum MyStates {
                    FIRST,
                    SECOND,
                    THIRD,
                   }
```

Every time I access them it prints it by the names I have given them. Is there a way to get their indexes? Ex. FIRST would be = 1, and so forth. Thanks

> **Related:**
>   [Enum with int value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681976/enum-with-int-value-in-java)

Comment: Why do you want indexes, instead of the values that you defined?

Comment: The index of the first element is almost always 0 in Java. (The only exception I can think of is JDBC)

Comment: Its not exactly a duplicate. The question here is not about defining a number for each enumeration object but getting its "ordinal".

Comment: @morja: If you want it to start from `1`, it's not an ordinal.

Comment: @SLaks: true, but as I understand it, its only about getting any index, not necessarily starting from 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ordinal()` function.

```
MyStates.FIRST.ordinal();
```