# Java ~ Send an enum over a socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, enums

What is the best way to send an enum value through sockets? Is there a way to convert an enum value to an int and vice versa?
Like:

```
Enum values {
    value1,
    value2
}

int value = (int)value1;
And...
values value2 = (value) value;
```

Would be very nice to send this over the internet!
Thanks all!

Bas

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681976/enum-with-int-value-in-java

Comment: No, I don't want to add attributes to values, I just want to send an Enum value that is the smame on the server & client through sockets. thanks for your comment ;)

Comment: Try [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/enum.html#ORDINAL).

Comment: Assuming that enum is same on both sides: `int ord = value.ordina2()` on one side, `values value2 = values.values()[ord]` on other. Please, name your enum values conventionally.

Comment: You can use this approach mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292790/convert-integer-value-to-matching-java-enum

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. There's a well-documented answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either marshall to `int`:

```
int ordinal = values.value1.ordinal()

//unmarshalling
values.values[ordinal];
```

or to `String`:

```
String name = values.value1.name();

//unmarshalling
values.valueOf(name);
```

The former saves some spaces (32-bits as opposed to varying-length strings) but is harder to maintain, e.g. rearranging `enum` values will break `ordinal()` backward compatibility. On the other hand `ordinal()` allows you to rename `enum` values...

Comment: That (And Banthars andswer) worked fine. Now anther question: What is the Java function to get the same result as C#'s: this.cmd = (Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

Comment: @Basaa: technically this should be a second question (it is more likely you will receive an answer), but have a look at this: stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761

Comment: I would use the name if you can. e.g. with `dataOutput.writeUTF(value.name())` and `Enum e = Values.forName(dataInput.readUTF())` as this is more readable as well.

Comment: Would this be the recommended/a reasonable approach, or would it be better practice to use an `ObjectOutputStream` and corresponding `ObjectInputStream` to send and receive an `enum` respectively?