# Using integer values and String identifier in an Enum

Tags: java, enums

So I currently have two enums:

```
public enum AuthorizationLevel 
    {   
        FULL,
        HALF,
        NONE;
    };


public enum DatabaseLoggingLevel
{
    HIGH,
    MED,
    LOW,
    AUTH_ONLY,
    NONE
}
```

I want to be able to associate integers with the values in the enums so that I can have code like so:

```
if(databaseLoggingLevel < ClassName.DatabaseLoggingLevel.HIGH) return;
```

This is just so that certain logging is disabled when the level is less than `HIGH`. I thought about making a helper function that returns an integer value associated with each enum value with a switch statement, but that seems hacky. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an integer instance field to your enum, and add a parameterized constructor:

```
enum AuthorizationLevel {

    FULL(1), HALF(2), NONE(3);

    private final int level;

    private AuthorizationLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
};
```

Note that there is an `ordinal()` method which will give you position of your enum constants, but you should avoid using it. Again, quoting [Effective Java Item - 31 (Use instance fields instead of ordinal)](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PR10&lpg=PR10&dq=Effective+Java+Item+31&source=bl&ots=yYJnMen5O_&sig=8VQVA0z44gWmg4zOJRoY9oyp6EE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N7ooUrmmDMSQrQe6sIDwDA&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Effective%20Java%20Item%2031&f=false):

> If the constants are reordered, the numberOfMusicians method will
>   break. If you want to **add a second enum constant associated with an
>   int value that you’ve already used**, you’re out of luck.
>
> Also, you can’t add a constant for an int value without adding
>   constants for all intervening int values. For example, suppose you
>   want to add a constant representing a triple quartet, which consists
>   of twelve musicians. There is no standard term for an ensemble
>   consisting of eleven musicians, so you are forced to add a dummy
>   constant for the unused int value (11). At best, this is ugly. If many
>   int values are unused, it’s impractical.

Comment: Yup exactly what I was looking for. I thought I remember this sort of syntax from somewhere. Thank you! I'll accept once the timer is up.

Comment: For enums, I typically recommend using the "final" keyword on fields, like `private final int val;`

Comment: @StormeHawke. Yeah, I missed that. I too prefer that way.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the constructor of your enum to add the Integer value.

```
public enum DatabaseLoggingLevel {
  HIGH(1),
  MED(2),
  LOW(3),
  AUTH_ONLY(4),
  NONE(5);

  private final Integer value;

  //For getByValue(). See Rohit's comment
  private static final DatabaseLoggingLevel[] VALUES = DatabaseLoggingLevel.values();

  private DatabaseLoggingLevel(Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Integer getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  //Bonus : getter by value:
  public static DatabaseLoggingLevel getByValue(Integer value) {
    for(DatabaseLoggingLevel e: VALUES) {
      if(e.getValue().equals(value)) {
        return e;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. You are missing a semi-colon after the last enum constant. 2. Why use `Integer` instead of `int`?  3. `DatabaseLoggingLevel.values()` will create an array every time that method is called. It would better to cache the array in a field itself.  4. That method would really be a bonus, if the value is a string. In case of integer, I don't see any major use for it.

Comment: 1: Edited. 2: I don't like literals, my personal choice. 3: Edited. 4: this one already exists : Enum#valueOf(String s);

Comment: *2. I don't like literals* -  I'm talking about primitive type int instead of wrapper classes. And if you don't like primitive types, I feel sorry for you and your fellow programmers. You might end up creating unneccessary objects.

Comment: Primitives vs Objects is a debate that does not takes place in this thread. It is my personal design choice to always use Objects (except in consuming algorithms). When I want some performance, I code in C.

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum DatabaseLoggingLevel
{
    HIGH(1),
    MED(2),
    LOW(3),
    AUTH_ONLY(4),
    NONE(5)

    private int code;

    private DatabaseLoggingLevel(int code) {
      this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() { return code; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ordinal() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29). It gives you the position of the Value in the enum.

Comment: Quite dangerous. If you add one value in the enum, it will modify all ordinal().

Answer (score 2):

Rather than programming this in terms of "`enum`s are numbers", program this in terms of "`enum`s are smart". You can associate numbers with `enum`s (after all, `enum`s are instances of regular Java classes), but make that number private. Then you can add this method to the `enum`:

```
public boolean isAboveOrEqualTo(DatabaseLoggingLevel level) {
    ...
}
```

Then your conditional would look like this:

```
if (databaseLoggingLevel.isAboveOrEqualTo(ClassName.DatabaseLoggingLevel.HIGH)) {
    ...
}
```

Here is an explanation of how to associate numbers with enums: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1681976/335858).

Comment: while this is certainly more OO, its verbosity is rather offputting compared to simple integer comparison. That is, actually writing the `isAboveOrEqualTo` method, not the actual comparison in the if statement.

Comment: @thatidiotguy The problem with exposing `int`s is that doing so gives away too much implementation that one presumably would rather hide behind the `enum`. Had the information hiding not been an objective, there would be no reason to introduce an `enum` in the first place, as symbolic `int` constants would be quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

While both of the answers given already will do what you want I would recommend looking at Log4J as an alternative to rolling your own logging levels

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_overview.htm

Comment: I use that for text logging. This is much more application specific, but thank you.