# Translating iOS Enums to Android

Tags: android, ios, enums

I'm busy trying to translate some iOS code to Android code. The iOS code contains Enums, like the following:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, Traits) {
    TraitNumberOne = 1<<0,
    TraitNumberTwo = 1<<1,
);
```

I have never worked with Enums before in Android, and am having trouble interpreting the documentation and examples that are available. How would I translate the above example to Android code?

Comment: FYI to everyone reading this from a primarily Java background, the enum is `Traits`. `NS_OPTIONS` is a macro - the first item is the type (integer here) and the second is the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
public enum NS_OPTIONS {

    TraitNumberOne (1<<0),
    TraitNumberTwo (1<<1);

    private final int Option;

    public int getOption()
    {
         return Option;
    }

    private NS_OPTIONS(int option) {
       this.Option= option;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
   int value = NsOptions.TraitNumberOne.getOption();
```

Comment: I agree, sorry for that. In Java (and therefore Android), you don't assign integers to `enum` members. Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681976/). Oracle provides a [comprehensible tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) about `enum`s in Java.

Comment: I tried this setup, but indeed it doesn't work. I actually thought the Oracle tutorial wasn't that clear

Comment: @still_learning thanks, I thought you meant the minor typo, but that is indeed wrong

Comment: @Zero I personally think (almost) none of the Oracle tutorials are *clear* or *complete*, but they get you started.

Comment: It took me a while to understand this concept, but it's working now :) . Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Java enums are relatively simple, but can be made more complex to fit whatever needs you want to use them for.  If you just want the type-safety of an enum, you can just declare the variable names like this:

```
public enum Traits{
    TraitNumberOne,
    TraitNumberTwo
}
```

If you want more advanced features of an enum, it's treated exactly like a class that is instantiated statically for each item in the enum.  So, you can have a constructor and input whatever value you want associated with each individual item, like so:

```
public enum Traits{
    TraitNumberOne(0x01),
    TraitNumberTwo(0x02),

    // future items go here
    ;  // don't forget the semi-colon, which indicates the list of items is ending

    // now, create a private variable to store the data
    private final int data;

    // and the constructor to set the data
    private NsOptions(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    // now, you can provide an accessor to provide access to the data
    public int getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

You can use the above enum like this:

```
Traits currentOptions = Traits.TraitNumberOne;
int optionsData = currentOptions.getData();
```

Comment: Just FYI, the enum name should be `Traits`. `NS_OPTIONS` is a macro.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of NS_OPTIONS is to allow all possible combinations of the enumerated values to be represented by one value (this is why bitwise operators are used). In Java, I guess the equivalent would be:

```
public enum Permission {
    TraitNumberOne (0b01),
    TraitNumberTwo (0b10);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can implement in android like ,

```
       public enum NS_OPTIONS{
             TraitNumberOne(1),TraitNumberTwo(2);

             private int type;

             NS_OPTIONS(int type){
                 this.type = type;
             }

             public int getType(){
                  return type;
              }

    }
```

and if you want to use above enum from your class you can use it like,

```
      int i =NS_OPTIONS.TraitNumberOne;//which will return 1
      int j =NS_OPTIONS.TraitNumberTwo;//which will return 2;
```

Comment: Just FYI, the enum name should be `Traits`. `NS_OPTIONS` is a macro.