# Can I add enums inside another enums using Java?

Tags: java, enums

Can I add enums inside other enums? For example:

```
public enum Enum1 {
    VALUE1;
}
public enum Enum2 {
    Enum1,
    VALUE2;
}
```

Note: I already know that you can do it like this way:

```
public enum Action
{
   FOO,
   BAR;
   enum MOVE
   {
     UP,
     DOWN,
     LEFT,
     RIGHT 
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/

Comment: Your first code doesn't make sense since an enum identifier has to be, well, an identifier, like any other, and suggests an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) -- what issue are you trying to solve with this? You already know that that "code" does not compile, and so you know that it's not legal.

Comment: @killjoy I don't want to extend the enum, I just want to have it like another property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can enums be subclassed to add new elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/can-enums-be-subclassed-to-add-new-elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Java Enum referencing another enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172178)

Comment: I think the closest you can get is to wrap it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Enum referencing another enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172178/java-enum-referencing-another-enum)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It was just a generic example to know how I can do that. If you want to know my real problem: I have an enum to display output messages and I want to "extend" the funtionality adding more output messages. Like this:
public enum GenericResponse {
 
 SUCCESS(1, "Successful operation"),
 SERVER_ERROR(2, "Error processing request"),
 MISSING_PARAMETERS(3, "Missing parameters");
}
public enum AuthenticationResponse {
     //Generic messages
    NOT_ALLOWED(4, "User not allowed");
}

Comment: If you need flexible and extensible messages, then don't use Java enums for this. Instead use a plain Java class, one where Strings can be added as needed, perhaps via database or via text setup file.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Enum1 {
    VALUE1;
}
public enum Enum2 {
    Enum1, // Enum1 is just constant
    VALUE2;
}
```

It's possible, but `Enum1` in `Enum2` is just constant (without any dependency with `Enum1` enum), however you can use something like this:

```
public enum Enum1 {
   VALUE1;
}

public enum Enum2 {
    VALUE1 (Enum1.VALUE1),
    VALUE2 (null);

    private final Enum1 enum1;

    Enum2(com.github.vedenin.services.image.filter.Enum1 enum1) {
        this.enum1 = enum1;
    }

    public Enum1 getEnum1() {
        return enum1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make them implement the same interface for increased functionality