# How to inject extended enums via Spring?

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414904/529411) solution to extending java enums.

How do I inject the extended enums via Spring config when a bean has the interface as property. For example,

```
class Foo {
  Day dayProp;

  public setDayProp(Day day) {
     this.dayProp = day;
  }
}
```

This gives an error 'failed to convert java.lang.String to interface Day'. I've also tried specifying the entire path.

```
<bean id="foo1" class="Foo">
  <property name="dayProp" value="SAT" />
</bean>
```

Comment: It's usually helpful to provide the error you receive as it often helps determine the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit of experimentation, I got this working using [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html)

```
<property name="dayProp" value="#{ T(path.for.WeekendDay).SAT }" />
```

But I would love to hear of alternative solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Spring uses reflection to determine the type of property anyway.
Have you tried just "SAT"?