# static final methods in enum

Tags: java, oop, enums

So I have looked around google and SO , I cannot find a example or explanation of : What is the purpose of `static` `final` methods in `enum`?

What I understand :

1. Methods declare `static` can be accessed like function/procedural languages.
2. `final` means you can't *override* it. Can't change the reference. As assylias pointed out in comments `static` can't be overridden either.
3. `enum`s can't be subclassed, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/java-extend-enum).

So what's the point of `static` `final` methods in `enum`s if it will never be *overridden* since there won't be a subclass?

Comment: a static method can't be overriden in any case...

Comment: @Henry Static methods can't be overridden either.

Comment: @ assylias I should add that in point two.

Comment: So I think your question is really" "is there any usefulness of using the `final` modifier on any enum method, whether static or not?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By making a static method final, [you prevent it from being hidden](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3) (only instance methods can be overriden) by a subclass.

Since enum can't be subclassed, making a static method final is superfluous but not forbidden.

Note: technically, each enum constant that has a class body [implicitly defines an anonymous class that extends the enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1-300). But since [inner classes may not declare static methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-130), the static final method could not be hidden in such a constant's class body.

Comment: +1 Actually there are cases where Enum can be subclassed, for example in `enum SomeEnum { VALUE1{}, VALUE2{}; }` VALUE1{} is anonymous class of `SomeEnum` type. But since we can't add static methods to non static inner classes (like anonymous classes) using `final` with `static` here is overkill.

Comment: @Pshemo That's a good point - I have edited my answer and added references.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to see why `static` methods make sense, so I guess the question is about the `final` modifier.

`final` serves no purpose here, except maybe make the code a bit easier to read, but not by much.

It's similar to the way `interface` methods are often written as `public void foo();`, even though interface members are always public anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In Java Enum types are used to represent fixed set of constants and making it static final helps its initialisation only once, single copy to be shared across all instances, accessing the variable with the class name and with final its more like a read-only

Answer (score 0):

When you declare instances of an enum you can override the enum's methods, essentially enum instances are implemented as (or thought of) as subclasses.  `static` methods can't be overridden in any case but the implication in the OP and other answers that `final` is superfluous for an `enum` is false.

Comment: You can't add a static method to enum constants.