# Java- Concatenating Enums?

Tags: java, enums

I have a java enum containing some elements, and I want a second enum that contains the same elements as the first, plus additional ones.

Is there a way to tell Java to create a new enum by taking the first and adding the extra elements onto it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this question: [Can enums be subclassed to add new elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/java-extend-enum)

The consensus is that it is not possible