# Suggest proper Design for Java integer constants extension

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I am sorry if this question was asked before, but I need a **good suggestion** to solve next design problem:

**Task**: given that we have a base service that operates with data of given set of types, we need to design support of extensions for that service that has extended type set.

**Bad Solution**:

```
class BaseServiceType {
    public static final int TYPE_A = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_B = 1;
    public static final int LAST_USED_BASE_TYPE_INDEX = TYPE_B;
}
```

And its extension

```
class ExtendedServiceType extends BaseServiceType {
   public static final int TYPE_E = LAST_USED_BASE_TYPE_INDEX + 1;
   public static final int TYPE_F = LAST_USED_BASE_TYPE_INDEX + 2;
}
```

My task is fairly simple that has only one extension. I am not trying to solve more general problem with multiple independent extensions.

I have a feeling that `enum` would work here, but no idea if it feasible.

Comment: the question is not fully clear :(

Comment: Check [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/java-extend-enum) about extending enums. I think it will be helpful for your situation.

Comment: Enums are immutable, you can not add new types during runtime. I don't know if I got your question right, but this might be a problem. If there are no new services added during runtime, you could use Enums

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/java-extend-enum

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion, but I doubt that introducing new type would not require additional wrapping to use those types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to build the ids dynamically.  Class initilization is thread safe so you can do this.

```
class BaseServiceType {
    protected static int id = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_A = id++;
    public static final int TYPE_B = id++;
}
```

And its extension

```
class ExtendedServiceType extends BaseServiceType {
   public static final int TYPE_E = id++;
   public static final int TYPE_F = id++;
}


class AlsoExtendedServiceType extends BaseServiceType {
   public static final int TYPE_X = id++;
   public static final int TYPE_Y = id++;
}
```

The only problem is the order classes are initialized change the ids.  If this matters, you need to access the classes in the order you need.

Comment: Great idea. I love it. Well, would it have more sense to use strings instead of ints?

Comment: @ACM64 You could, but I don't know how you would like to generate them automagically. ;)