# Set enum values

Tags: java

I have a enum class that has values A,B. Here is the class:

```
@XmlType(name = "MemberType")
@XmlEnum
public enum MemberType {
    A,
    B;
    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static MemberType fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }
}
```

I have another enum class similar to this one that has the same values A, and B. This class is generated from my WSDL, and I have no control over its code. What I basically want to do is, equate the two enum values.

Basically say `MemberType.A = WSDLClass.A`, something like that. What can I try next?

Comment: Do you really have no power over the code generated? Because a solution might be to use custom JAXB binding to map MemberType to an existing enum when the code is generated.

Comment: No I don't. I wish that was an option. Lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot assign one enum type to a different type (and [you can't have enum extend some abstract superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/can-enums-be-subclassed-to-add-new-elements)), you can declare a static method (either in `MemberType` or in some utility class), mapping from `WSDLClass` to `MemberType`:

```
public static MemberType fromWsdl(WSDLClass w) {
    if (w==null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      switch (w) {
         case WSDLClass.A: return MemberType.A;
         case WSDLClass.B: return MemberType.B;
         default: return null;
      }
    }
}
```

Then you would use that function as follow:

```
import static xyz.MemberType.fromWsdl;
...
MemberType m = ...;
WSDLClass w = ...;
if (m.equals(fromWsdl(w))) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If the names are strictly the same, I suppose you can :

```
private MemberType convertEnum(WSDLClass type) {
    return Enum.valueOf(MemberType.class, type.name());
}
```

If the names are not strictly the same or could differ in the future you are going to have to do :

```
private MemberType convertEnum(WSDLClass type) {
    MemberType memberType;
    switch (type) {
    case A:
        memberType = MemberType.A;
        break;
    case B:
        memberType = MemberType.B;
        break;
    default:
        memberType = null;
        break;
    }
    return memberType;
}
```

If you want to use the first solution but the fact that it throw NullPointerException if type is null bother you can use [EnumUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#getEnum%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) from Apache Commons Lang.