# Subclassing ENUMs

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, subclass

The approach is quite simple. I want to subclass an ENUM A with B so that B inherits all values of A.

I'm aware that this post [Can enums be subclassed to add new elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/can-enums-be-subclassed-to-add-new-elements/40532219#40532219) already describes various solutions (including mine). However I don't think my last post will be even read after all the answers. So I made a fresh post with my answer in the hopes this solutions will be seen and maybe even used.

Comment: That other question has over 300 upvotes. Answers are more likely to get seen there than here.

Comment: So you're posting an existing question? That is the very definition of a duplicate. You're posting an answer that already exists? Why does that anything - if you like the approach and it is given in another answer, upvote it.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you saying. I'm just being realistic here. How likely is it that my answer gets upvoted over answers that already several hundred votes and that answer is already being marked as correct? I myself wouldn't necessarily read that far below.

Comment: @Dr4gon So it's all about wanting points?

Comment: @Kayaman: Do you really think with nearly three years of membership and 100 points I care about points? 

You can believe me or not that's entirely up to you. However I just like to share and started to do that more often. If this is the reaction to me trying to share I'm not sure I'm likely to continue contributing.

Comment: @Dr4gon That's entirely your decision. If you do continue, you'll have to abide by the rules, understand that votes don't necessarily go "as they should" (my best voted answer is an absolute trivial remark) and generally learn this is a thankless job. If you think you have an elegant solution, group it with others. At least it'll be among the best. Someone might be looking for exactly something like it. In many cases there may also be multiple correct/best answers as for example versions increase, so you have all possible best solutions nicely in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share this elegant approach of my colleague for subclassing which follows the interface approach and beyond.

Please be aware that we use custom exceptions here and this code won't compile unless you replace it with your exceptions.

The documentation is extensive and I hope it's understandable for most of you.

The interface that every subclassed enum needs to implement.

```
public interface Parameter {
  /**
   * Retrieve the parameters name.
   *
   * @return the name of the parameter
   */
  String getName();

  /**
   * Retrieve the parameters type.
   *
   * @return the {@link Class} according to the type of the parameter
   */
  Class<?> getType();

  /**
   * Matches the given string with this parameters value pattern (if applicable). This helps to find
   * out if the given string is a syntactically valid candidate for this parameters value.
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string to check for
   * @return <code>true</code> in case this parameter has no pattern defined or the given string
   *         matches the defined one, <code>false</code> in case <code>valueStr</code> is
   *         <code>null</code> or an existing pattern is not matched
   */
  boolean match(final String valueStr);

  /**
   * This method works as {@link #match(String)} but throws an exception if not matched.
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string to check for
   * @throws ArgumentException with code
   *           <dl>
   *           <dt>PARAM_MISSED</dt>
   *           <dd>if <code>valueStr</code> is <code>null</code></dd>
   *           <dt>PARAM_BAD</dt>
   *           <dd>if pattern is not matched</dd>
   *           </dl>
   */
  void matchEx(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException;

  /**
   * Parses a value for this parameter from the given string. This method honors the parameters data
   * type and potentially other criteria defining a valid value (e.g. a pattern).
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string to parse the parameter value from
   * @return the parameter value according to the parameters type (see {@link #getType()}) or
   *         <code>null</code> in case <code>valueStr</code> was <code>null</code>.
   * @throws ArgumentException in case <code>valueStr</code> is not parsable as a value for this
   *           parameter.
   */
  Object parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException;

  /**
   * Converts the given value to its external form as it is accepted by {@link #parse(String)}. For
   * most (ordinary) parameters this is simply a call to {@link String#valueOf(Object)}. In case the
   * parameter types {@link Object#toString()} method does not return the external form (e.g. for
   * enumerations), this method has to be implemented accordingly.
   *
   * @param value <i>mandatory</i> - the parameters value
   * @return the external form of the parameters value, never <code>null</code>
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the given <code>value</code> does not match
   *           {@link #getType()}
   */
  String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException;
}
```

The implementing ENUM base class.

```
public enum Parameters implements Parameter {
  /**
   * ANY ENUM VALUE
   */
  VALUE(new ParameterImpl<String>("VALUE", String.class, "[A-Za-z]{3,10}"));

  /**
   * The parameter wrapped by this enum constant.
   */
  private Parameter param;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param param <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #param}
   */
  private Parameters(final Parameter param) {
    this.param = param;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.param.getName();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Class<?> getType() {
    return this.param.getType();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean match(final String valueStr) {
    return this.param.match(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void matchEx(final String valueStr) {
    this.param.matchEx(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Object parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException {
    return this.param.parse(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    return this.param.toString(value);
  }
}
```

The subclassed ENUM which "inherits" from base class.

```
public enum ExtendedParameters implements Parameter {
  /**
   * ANY ENUM VALUE
   */
  VALUE(my.package.name.VALUE);

  /**
   * EXTENDED ENUM VALUE
   */
  EXTENDED_VALUE(new ParameterImpl<String>("EXTENDED_VALUE", String.class, "[0-9A-Za-z_.-]{1,20}"));

  /**
   * The parameter wrapped by this enum constant.
   */
  private Parameter param;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param param <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #param}
   */
  private Parameters(final Parameter param) {
    this.param = param;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.param.getName();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Class<?> getType() {
    return this.param.getType();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean match(final String valueStr) {
    return this.param.match(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void matchEx(final String valueStr) {
    this.param.matchEx(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Object parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException {
    return this.param.parse(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    return this.param.toString(value);
  }
}
```

Finally the generic ParameterImpl to add some utilities.

```
public class ParameterImpl<T> implements Parameter {
  /**
   * The default pattern for numeric (integer, long) parameters.
   */
  private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");

  /**
   * The default pattern for parameters of type boolean.
   */
  private static final Pattern BOOLEAN_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("0|1|true|false");

  /**
   * The name of the parameter, never <code>null</code>.
   */
  private final String name;

  /**
   * The data type of the parameter.
   */
  private final Class<T> type;

  /**
   * The validation pattern for the parameters values. This may be <code>null</code>.
   */
  private final Pattern validator;

  /**
   * Shortcut constructor without <code>validatorPattern</code>.
   *
   * @param name <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #name}
   * @param type <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #type}
   */
  public ParameterImpl(final String name, final Class<T> type) {
    this(name, type, null);
  }

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param name <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #name}
   * @param type <i>mandatory</i> - the value for {@link #type}
   * @param validatorPattern - <i>optional</i> - the pattern for {@link #validator}
   *          <dl>
   *          <dt style="margin-top:0.25cm;"><i>Note:</i>
   *          <dd>The default validation patterns {@link #NUMBER_PATTERN} or
   *          {@link #BOOLEAN_PATTERN} are applied accordingly.
   *          </dl>
   */
  public ParameterImpl(final String name, final Class<T> type, final String validatorPattern) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    if (null != validatorPattern) {
      this.validator = Pattern.compile(validatorPattern);

    } else if (Integer.class == this.type || Long.class == this.type) {
      this.validator = NUMBER_PATTERN;
    } else if (Boolean.class == this.type) {
      this.validator = BOOLEAN_PATTERN;
    } else {
      this.validator = null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean match(final String valueStr) {
    if (null == valueStr) {
      return false;
    }
    if (null != this.validator) {
      final Matcher matcher = this.validator.matcher(valueStr);
      return matcher.matches();
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void matchEx(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException {
    if (false == this.match(valueStr)) {
      if (null == valueStr) {
        throw ArgumentException.createEx(ErrorCode.PARAM_MISSED, "The value must not be null",
            this.name);
      }
      throw ArgumentException.createEx(ErrorCode.PARAM_BAD, "The value must match the pattern: "
          + this.validator.pattern(), this.name);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Parse the parameters value from the given string value according to {@link #type}. Additional
   * the value is checked by {@link #matchEx(String)}.
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>optional</i> - the string value to parse the value from
   * @return the parsed value, may be <code>null</code>
   * @throws ArgumentException in case the parameter:
   *           <ul>
   *           <li>does not {@link #matchEx(String)} the {@link #validator}</li>
   *           <li>cannot be parsed according to {@link #type}</li>
   *           </ul>
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the type {@link #type} cannot be handled. This is a
   *           programming error.
   */
  @Override
  public T parse(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException, InternalServiceException {
    if (null == valueStr) {
      return null;
    }
    this.matchEx(valueStr);

    if (String.class == this.type) {
      return this.type.cast(valueStr);
    }
    if (Boolean.class == this.type) {
      return this.type.cast(Boolean.valueOf(("1".equals(valueStr)) || Boolean.valueOf(valueStr)));
    }
    try {
      if (Integer.class == this.type) {
        return this.type.cast(Integer.valueOf(valueStr));
      }
      if (Long.class == this.type) {
        return this.type.cast(Long.valueOf(valueStr));
      }
    } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
      throw ArgumentException.createEx(ErrorCode.PARAM_BAD, "The value cannot be parsed as "
          + this.type.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + ".", this.name);
    }

    return this.parseOther(valueStr);
  }

  /**
   * Field access for {@link #name}.
   *
   * @return the value of {@link #name}.
   */
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  /**
   * Field access for {@link #type}.
   *
   * @return the value of {@link #type}.
   */
  @Override
  public Class<T> getType() {
    return this.type;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public final String toString(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    if (false == this.type.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
      throw new InternalServiceException(ErrorCode.PANIC,
          "Parameter.toString(): Bad type of value. Expected {0} but is {1}.", this.type.getName(),
          value.getClass().getName());
    }
    if (String.class == this.type || Integer.class == this.type || Long.class == this.type) {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    if (Boolean.class == this.type) {
      return Boolean.TRUE.equals(value) ? "1" : "0";
    }

    return this.toStringOther(value);
  }

  /**
   * Parse parameter values of other (non standard types). This method is called by
   * {@link #parse(String)} in case {@link #type} is none of the supported standard types (currently
   * String, Boolean, Integer and Long). It is intended for extensions.
   * <dl>
   * <dt style="margin-top:0.25cm;"><i>Note:</i>
   * <dd>This default implementation always throws an InternalServiceException.
   * </dl>
   *
   * @param valueStr <i>mandatory</i> - the string value to parse the value from
   * @return the parsed value, may be <code>null</code>
   * @throws ArgumentException in case the parameter cannot be parsed according to {@link #type}
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the type {@link #type} cannot be handled. This is a
   *           programming error.
   */
  protected T parseOther(final String valueStr) throws ArgumentException, InternalServiceException {
    throw new InternalServiceException(ErrorCode.PANIC,
        "ParameterImpl.parseOther(): Unsupported parameter type: " + this.type.getName());
  }

  /**
   * Convert the values of other (non standard types) to their external form. This method is called
   * by {@link #toString(Object)} in case {@link #type} is none of the supported standard types
   * (currently String, Boolean, Integer and Long). It is intended for extensions.
   * <dl>
   * <dt style="margin-top:0.25cm;"><i>Note:</i>
   * <dd>This default implementation always throws an InternalServiceException.
   * </dl>
   *
   * @param value <i>mandatory</i> - the parameters value
   * @return the external form of the parameters value, never <code>null</code>
   * @throws InternalServiceException in case the given <code>value</code> does not match
   *           {@link #getClass()}
   */
  protected String toStringOther(final Object value) throws InternalServiceException {
    throw new InternalServiceException(ErrorCode.PANIC,
        "ParameterImpl.toStringOther(): Unsupported parameter type: " + this.type.getName());
  }
}
```