# Can we change GWT Bootstrap 3 ButtonCell Icon Dynamically?

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap, gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I have a GWT bootstrap 3 button as a [ButtonCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html) created with IconType and ButtonType:

```
public abstract class ButtonColumn<T> extends Column<T, String> {
    public ButtonColumn(IconType iconType, ButtonType buttonType) {
        this(new ButtonCell(buttonType, iconType));
    }
}
```

So when I create the button, I do

```
new ButtonColumn<Object>(IconType.PLAY, ButtonType.SUCCESS) {
  @Override
  public void onClick(Object obj) {
    doStuff(obj);
  }
};
```

I want to change my button IconType onClick. Is it possible to achieve it?
And can I create a custom IconType extending the GWT [IconType Enum](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/com/github/gwtbootstrap/client/ui/constants/IconType.html)? I wanted to put an animated icon (like a [loading icon](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-circle-o-notch)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can not change the button's icon in a row, especially when you create the whole column with an icon already specified. But you can `redraw()` a row and this could be a way to achieve what you want.

I use [AbstractCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html) to render a button and [onBrowserEvent](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html#onBrowserEvent-com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context-com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element-C-com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent-com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater-):

- first create an AbstractCell with `ClickEvent` in `consumedEvents` parameter
- in the `render()` method render a button based on the *clicked* state
- in the `onBrowserEvent()` method change the *clicked* state and re-render the row

The *clicked* state is best to be kept in the table's underlying data type so it is available for each row.

Here is a complete working example code:

```
final CellTable<TableType> table = new CellTable<TableType>();

AbstractCell<TableType> buttonCell = new AbstractCell<ButtonCellTest.TableType>(ClickEvent.getType().getName()) {
    @Override
    public void render(Context context, TableType value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setType(ButtonType.SUCCESS);
        button.setSize(ButtonSize.SMALL);
        button.add(new Icon(value.isClicked() ? IconType.CHECK : IconType.TIMES));
        sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(button.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, TableType value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<TableType> valueUpdater) {
        value.setClicked(!value.isClicked());
        // ... do stuff...
        table.redrawRow(context.getIndex());
    }
};
table.addColumn(new Column<TableType, TableType>(buttonCell) {
    @Override
    public TableType getValue(TableType object) {
        return object;
    }
});

ArrayList<TableType> rowData = new ArrayList<TableType>();
rowData.add(new TableType("row 1"));
rowData.add(new TableType("row 2"));
...
table.setRowData(rowData);
```

And example table's data type keeping the *clicked* state:

```
public class TableType {
    String text;
    boolean clicked = false;

    public TableType(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public boolean isClicked() {
        return clicked;
    }

    public void setClicked(boolean clicked) {
        this.clicked = clicked;
    }
}
```

---

As for extending the `IconType` enum - no, you can not extend an enum in Java. See this question for example: [Can enums be subclassed to add new elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/can-enums-be-subclassed-to-add-new-elements).

You could try to add your own `CSS` class but this should be asked as another question to get precise answers.

Comment: `table.redrawRow(context.getIndex());` worked for me. Instead of using the OnBrowserEvent() I used the onClick, passing the row id on the click event. That´s possible cause we have an own class extending AbstractCell. Thank you!