# Java: an enum in an extending class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, enums

I have a class that extends another one. It should have an enum that should have certain values for the extending class, so I have the following:

```
public class Shepherd extends Dog {

    public enum Color {
        BLACK,
        GREEN,
        INVISIBLE
    }

    // ...

}
```

This enum should be a part of the extending class, as another class that extends `Dog` should have its own enum with its own values, that's why I can't make the `Color` enum a part of the `Dog` class. For example:

```
public class Corgi extends Dog {

    public enum Color {
        RED,
        BLACK,
        SABLE
    }

    // ...

}
```

Also, I have a constructor:

```
public class Shepherd extends Dog {

    public enum Color {
        // ...
    }

    public Shepherd(Color color) {
        super(color);
    }

    // ...

}
```

I need the base class (`Dog`) to have the `color` field that would be accessible from other methods of the same base class (`Dog`).

```
public class Dog {

    public enum Color { } // not sure in that :-(

    private Color color;

    public Dog(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Obviously, it won't work, as `Dog.Color` is not the same type as `Shepherd.Color`. OK, let's do it another way:

```
public class Shepherd extends Dog<Shepherd> {

    // ...

    public Shepherd(Color color) {
        super(color);
    }

    // ...

}
```

```
public class Dog<T extends Dog> {

    public enum Color { } // ???

    private T.Color color;

    public Dog(T.Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public T.Color getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    // ...

}
```

And I'm still getting `incompatible types: Shepherd.Color cannot be converted to Dog.Color`. :-( Why doesn't Java accept it? The parameter has type `T.Color`, which should mean `Shepherd.Color` or `Corgi.Color` dependent on the class we use, isn't it?

Would anyone be so kind as to show me the correct way with an example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fear that what you want is not possible. There is no way to enforce that each subtype of `Dog` has a `Color`-enum defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums in Java [cannot be extended with new elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/can-enums-be-subclassed-to-add-new-elements) If you want two distinct classes to use two very similar Enums, the right approach is to make them both use the same single Enum class (`Color`).

Your best option for restricting the subset of Colors allowed for each type of `Dog` is runtime validation using an inherited superclass method - named, say, `getValidColors()`; and marking `color` as `final` so the validation cannot be (easily) bypassed.

```
public enum Color {
    BLACK, GREEN, INVISIBLE, RED, SABLE
}

public abstract class Dog {
    protected final Color color;
    public Dog(final Color color) {
        if (!this.getValidColors().contains(color)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(color);
        }
        this.color = color;
    }
    public abstract List<Color> getValidColors();
}

public class Shepherd extends Dog {
    public Shepherd(final Color color) {
        super(color);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Color> getValidColors() {
        return Arrays.asList(Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public class Corgi extends Dog {
    public Corgi(final Color color) {
        super(color);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Color> getValidColors() {
        return Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.BLACK, Color.SABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I went this way and came where I was heading.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be exacly what you want, but this is a way to solve it, but again it might not be what you want. Because I am using the Color as the generic field instead of the Dog Child itself.

Color interface

```
public interface IColor<C> {
    C getColor();
}
```

Dog.class

```
public class Dog<C extends IColor<? extends Enum<?>>> {

  private C color;

  public Dog(C color) {
      this.color = color;
  }

  public C getColor() {
      return color;
  }
}
```

Dog child color:

```
public enum ShepherdColor implements IColor<ShepherdColor> {
  BLACK,
  GREEN,
  INVISIBLE;

  @Override
  public ShepherdColor getColor() {
      return this;
  }
}
```

Dog Child class

```
public class Shepherd extends Dog<ShepherdColor> {
  public Shepherd(ShepherdColor color) {
      super(color);
  }
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Shepherd s = new Shepherd(ShepherdColor.GREEN);
  Dog<?> d = s;
  System.out.println(s.getColor());
  System.out.println(d.getColor());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basing contracts on static members (let alone that those members are nested types) won't work.

What you need is a type for the `color` instance field in `Dog`. It's a type, that's it; and after that, it needs to be abstract enough to be meaningfully referenced across your type hierarchy.

Now, talking about your code, I can think of two ways in which you can write a `Color` type that is used by your classes.

1. Use an interface as the base `Color` type. This interface can be implemented by your enums. I don't see how `Dog` uses `color`, so I'm assuming it's just a type.

   ```
   interface Color {}

   public class Dog {
       //...
       private Color color;
       //...
   }

   class Corgi extends Dog {
       public enum CorgiColor implements Color {
           RED, BLACK, SABLE
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Make your types generic:

   ```
   class Dog<E extends Enum<E>, T extends Dog<E, T>> {
       //...
       private E color;
       //...
   }

   class Corgi extends Dog<CorgiColor, Corgi> {
       public enum CorgiColor {
           RED, BLACK, SABLE
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

There may be other ways, but each will have its own pros and cons, depending on how you use the `color` value.