# Variable of type of enum class

Tags: java, enums

I need to specify an Enum class as a class variable in another Enum like so:

```
enum A {}
enum B {
  Class<Enum> clazz;
}
```

So that clazz can point to any Enum class like A or B or any other.
Is it possible to do it in Java?

Comment: Try enum B { A clazz; }

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, specifically? This smells like an XY.

Comment: @artem, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/can-enums-be-subclassed-to-add-new-elements

Comment: @Horse no, in my case it doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I need to store an Enum for a parser to let it know how to process certain additional data properly for a value of Enum B.

Comment: What does "store an enum" mean, exactly? Why do you need to store it, since Java knows what enum type `A.FOO` is?

Comment: Store an Enum class to point to the right data structure.

Comment: In my case, based on the value of Enum B like `B.FOO` I need to have an enum class to parse the additional data to.

Comment: However, we are not trying to solve the XY problem here. I created this question so that users of stackoverflow would be able to find an answer to this particular interesting question related to Java language itself. The XY problem should be a different question asked on "Algorithms" version of stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Declare a member field:

```
public Class< ? extends Enum > clazz ;
```

## Details

Apparently yes, you can hold a enum `Class` object as a member field on another enum’s class definition.

In this example code we define our own enum, `Animal`, providing for two named instances. Our enum carries a member field of type `Class`. In that member field, we store either of two enum classes passed to the constructor. We pass enum classes defined in the *java.time* package, [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) amd [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html).

```java
    enum Animal { 
        // Instances.
        DOG( DayOfWeek.class ) , CAT( Month.class )  ;

        // Member fields.
        final public Class clazz ;

        // Constructor
        Animal( Class c ) {
            this.clazz = c ;
        }
    }
```

Access that member field.

```
System.out.println( Animal.CAT.clazz.getCanonicalName() ) ;
```

Run this [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/vVT32K).

> java.time.Month

If you want to restrict your member field to hold only `Class` objects that happen to be enums, use [Java Generics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). Enums in Java are all, by definition, implicitly subclasses of `Enum`.

```java
    enum Animal { 
        DOG( DayOfWeek.class ) , CAT( Month.class )  ;
        final public Class< ? extends Enum > clazz ;
        Animal(  Class< ? extends Enum > c ) {
            this.clazz = c ;
        }
    }
```

In that code above, change the `Month.class` to `ArrayList.class` to get a compiler error. We declared our `clazz` member field as holding a `Class` object representing a class that is a subclass of `Enum`. The `Month` class is indeed a subclass of `Enum` while `ArrayList.class` is not.

Run that code with generics [live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Nb7vKk).

Comment: Technically, this is correct, but `EnumSet.allOf(clazz)` won't work

Comment: @Artem (a) You did not ask for `EnumSet.allof( clazz )` in your Question. (b) See [`Class#getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()). The Javadoc says: *Returns the elements of this enum class or null if this Class object does not represent an enum type.* So code would be: `Animal.CAT.clazz. getEnumConstants()` to get an array of all the months of the year. Feed that array to [`Set.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)) for an unmodifiable set of the enums.