# Java: How to get values from an arbitrary Enum class

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum containing reference to a class of enum like so:

```
enum Animal { 
  DOG(DayOfWeek.class),
  CAT(Month.class);

  public Class<? extends Enum> clazz;

  Animal(Class<? extends Enum> c) {
    this.clazz = c;
  }

  public String getValuesConcat() {
    String allValues = "";

    // The following line doesn't compile
    for (Object enumValue : EnumSet.allOf(clazz)) {
      allValues += " " + enumValue.toString();
    }

    return allValues;
  }
}
```

I couldn't figure out a way to store Enum class so that I can get the list of values from it later. Any clues?

Comment: You code compiles for me, and `Animal.DOG.getValuesConcat()` returns `MONDAY TUESDAY WEDNESDAY THURSDAY FRIDAY SATURDAY SUNDAY`. What error do you get?

Comment: Are you going to need the `clazz` member later? Or is it just to get the values?

Comment: FYI: This Question is derived from: [*Variable of type of enum class*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66309963/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using an `EnumSet`, I think it's cleaner to use [`Class#getEnumConstants`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()). This returns an array of your enum objects.

```
            for (Enum enumValue : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
                allValues += " " + enumValue.name();
            }
```

Be aware that this code will [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if `clazz` is not an `Enum`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the [correct Answer by tgdavies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66327194/642706) to get an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable) `Set` of your enum objects.

Pass the array of enum objects returned by `Class#getEnumConstants` to the [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)) method.

Here is a code example equivalent to your `Set.of( Animal.CAT.clazz.getEnumConstants() ) ;`.

```java
Set< Month > months = Set.of( Month.class.getEnumConstants() ) ;  // Pass array of enum objects to `Set.of` to produce an unmodifiable set.
        
System.out.println( "months: " + months ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/1R5bdX).

> months: [JANUARY, MAY, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER, MARCH, OCTOBER, JUNE, APRIL, AUGUST, JULY, SEPTEMBER, FEBRUARY]

Answer (score 1):

I totally overlooked that you need another enum's values.

Since the enum constructor is private anyway, why make your life hard by passing a Class object? Just pass the values instead. This should work as long as your enum contains at least one value:

```
enum Animal {
    DOG(DayOfWeek.values()),
    CAT(Month.values());

    public final Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz;
    private final Enum<?>[] values;

    <T extends Enum<T>> Animal(T[] values) {
        this.clazz = (Class<? extends Enum<?>>) values[0].getClass();
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String getValuesConcat() {
        return Arrays.stream(values).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }
}
```