# Is it possible to use Interfaces to extend Enum to give the Enum the Ability to extend the Options?

Tags: java

I have an enum class with these options:

- BOOLEAN
- DATE
- DOUBLE
- FLOAT
- INTEGER
- LOCAL_DATE

I want to allow other mod developers (I'm making currently an API mod for Minecraft Forge) to add new options to that enum. How can I do that?

Comment: there is something like that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414896/8312604. But I suppose it isn't gonna be helpful in your case.

Comment: You cannot do this with enums. You'll need to use an alternative approach, e.g. with interfaces, maybe an SPI or similar to detect the available options at runtime, etc.

Comment: Maybe you could rewrite your question to show how you are currently using an Enum and why you need an Enum. Then the question would be how to replace it with something extensible. One idea is to create an Interface, then have your own implementations that correspond to the  values provided. That way it is pretty clear what a user would have to do.

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance is not allowed for enums.

Comment: I mean using Interfaces. Read the Question.

Comment: @CuteKitsuneForever I did and attached a link to the approach with inerfaces as a comment to your question. But, as I said, probably it isn't gonna be helpful in your case.

Comment: @CuteKitsuneForever Nowhere does your question mention interfaces, you only mention enums. And enums are *not* extensible.